# How to make java reflections take dependencies classes too?

Tags: java, reflection, dependencies

i am using java reflections to get all classes names that contains TestNG test. So, i am doing this, and it's working fine:

```
String pack = "com.project.automation.tests";
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(pack))
        .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));
Set<Method> testMethods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Test.class);
```

Is there any way to take classes from maven dependencies too? I mean, if i have a dependency with a class that contains a TestNG test, so i want to reflections take that too. Do you know how to do that? Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "dependency"? Subclasses? Maven dependencies?

Comment: Depending on why you are doing that, a simple search in your IDE including dependencies may be easier.

Comment: But i need to make that search by code because i need that classes name to make some functionality. So, making search vía IDE is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should find all TestNG test classes that are on the classpath (of whatever you are running).  If the dependency TestNG classes are on the classpath, it will find them.

However, if your dependency is a production library JAR that you fetched from Maven Central, etc, the chances are that the JAR won't include the library's unit tests.  It is not normal practice to distribute unit tests in a production JAR.  And it is not normal practice to run dependent unit tests ... if you are not building the dependents yourself.

---

I'm not aware of any Maven plugin that can obtain JARs for dependent unit tests ... and I suspect that it is not technically possible.

Your best bet would be to download the dependent source code by hand, build it, and then manually add the dependents unit tests classes (or JARs) to the classpath of whatever application it is that is doing the searching.

Comment: Ok, i understand. But then, i want to make this: I want to implement this as a maven dependency into another project, and i want to make the reflection's search inside this "another project" classes. I mean, this class could recieve by param the package to search (from the project that implement this dependency) and i want to reflections find those classes located in this project that are TestNG tests. Is there any way to do this? Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: I think I have already answered all of that.  The classes need to be on the classpath, and you *probably* need to do that by hand.  (Or you may be lucky and find the unit tests in the production JAR ... but I'm guessing they are not, since you are asking this question.)